# How to execute HAWK signed REST methods using Springdoc Open API swagger UI?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui

I have Spring Boot RESTful application:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.7</version>
</parent>
```

All client requests are signed with HAWK:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.wealdtech.hawk</groupId>
    <artifactId>hawk-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Also I've enabled swagger-ui with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Is it possible somehow to execute hawk signed rest methods on that swagger-ui?
I've tried to use

```
@SecurityScheme(type = SecuritySchemeType.APIKEY, name = "api_key", in = SecuritySchemeIn.HEADER)
```

But it has no HAWK.